# Ubuntu - Access Local File using Browser

Tags: javascript, linux, flash, ubuntu, phantomjs

I need to automate the taking of screenshots of swf files, ideally using a headless browser. I installed phantomjs 1.4.1, which allows the use of the flash plugin.

This code successfully creates a png of a remotely hosted flash files:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.dhs.state.il.us/accessibility/tests/flash/video.html', function () {
window.setTimeout(function(){
    page.render('video.png');
    phantom.exit();
},3000);
});
```

However, with a a local file I get a blank png:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('file:///flashfiles/myfile.swf', function () {
window.setTimeout(function(){
    page.render('test.png');
    phantom.exit();
},3000);
});
```

This is the code I use to run my phantomjs script:

```
phantomjs --load-plugins=true snap.js
```

I am running this code on Ubuntu 14.04, what am I missing?

Comment: In that `page.open` try using `file://flashfiles/myfile.swf` (two forward slash).  Secondly... As a security measure, SWF files do not work if they're running from a non-web location (they need to run to be screenshot, right?). You need to go to your system settings (control panel) & find settings for installed Flash Player plugin **or** use this **[online version](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html#117502)** where you "edit locations" to browse to folder of your SWF. This way any SWF in that folder is trusted & should work as if online.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu server, so I don't have a system settings I can go to. Do you know how that can be done from the command line?

Comment: I don't think it's doable via command line. Did you try the **[web version](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html#117502)**? On that SWF (takes a moment to load) just click "**edit locations**" and you get same options/result just like  if you'd used Ubuntu settings or command line.

Comment: Also a bigger issue I've remembered is that you've used local `file://etc` yet browser code (html/JS) doesn't accept local file paths. You can try putting html (of grabber code) in same location as the SWF then change page.open URL to just basic filename : `page.open('myfile.swf', function ...etc etc`. This works when embedding so it might work for grabbing too. Finally make sure there are no issues with SWF itself (it runs fine locally etc)...

Comment: PhantomJS doesn't generally support flash regardless how you load it. Now I'm wondering if you really see something useful on the screenshot of the html page with flash content.